# Table criteria filter

Tags: vba, excel

My tables retrieve entries from the database through a dropdown list so they can have 1 to 500 entries, therefore auto-filter to remove blanks is inevitable.

I have tables across many sheets, however , hey don't start from the same row or column. In order to filter out blanks, I had to record a macro and assign it to a button but it takes about 30 seconds to process.

Is there a way to cut the processing time? Perhaps we don't have to choose each table/sheet individually but as a whole?

```
sub filteroutblanks()
       Sheets("Talent OutFlow").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TalentOutflow").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"
            Sheets("One-Pager Profile").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table18").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                "<>"
            Sheets("Internal Promotions").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("InternalPromotions").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"
            Sheets("External Hires").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ExternalHires").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"
            Sheets("Talent Inflow").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TalentInflow").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
                :="<>"
            Sheets("Exceptions-Overheads").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("StatusExceptions").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"
            Sheets("Talent Calibrations").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Calibrations").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
                :="<>"
            Sheets("Current CDN-U").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CurrentCDNorU").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"

            Sheets("Exits").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("LeaversTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
                :="<>"
            Sheets("Demotions").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DemotionsORexits").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="<>"
            Sheets("Current Vacancies").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                "<>"
            Sheets("Language").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Languages").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                "<>"
            Sheets("Mobility").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Mobility").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                "<>"
        End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be saying that this code was generated by the macro recorder, rather than written by you?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid Select and Activate whenever possible.  It is more efficient to reference the Objects directly then to work with then through the Selection method.  Watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Instead of selecting the worksheet and then referencing the **ActiveSheet**

```
Sheets("Current Vacancies").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

You can just refer to the ListObject directly by qualifying it by it's worksheet.

```
Sheets("Current Vacancies").ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Excel does not allow two ListObjects to share the same name so that the ListObjects range can be referenced directly by name.

```
Range("Table4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Refactoring the code to avoid selecting the worksheets will give a significant performance boost.

```
Sub filteroutblanks()
    Range("TalentOutflow").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Table18").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("InternalPromotions").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("ExternalHires").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("TalentInflow").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("StatusExceptions").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Calibrations").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("CurrentCDNorU").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("LeaversTable").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("DemotionsORexits").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Table4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Languages").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Mobility").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

You could further simplify the code by iterating over an Array of table names

```
Dim item As Variant

For Each item In Array("TalentOutflow", "Table18", "InternalPromotions", "ExternalHires", "TalentInflow", "StatusExceptions", "Calibrations", "CurrentCDNorU", "LeaversTable", "DemotionsORexits", "Table4", "Languages", "Mobility")
    Range(item).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Next
```

Disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating` and setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` will give you another speed boost.

Watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 40 - Disabling Screen Updates](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=3BI_IDXOAMg&index=44&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

```
Sub filteroutblanks2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim item As Variant

    For Each item In Array("TalentOutflow", "Table18", "InternalPromotions", "ExternalHires", "TalentInflow", "StatusExceptions", "Calibrations", "CurrentCDNorU", "LeaversTable", "DemotionsORexits", "Table4", "Languages", "Mobility")
        Range(item).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```